# OpenSuse 11 version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: python, libc, opensuse

I'm trying to get a script working in Python on a Suse Linux Server (OpenSuse 11):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
import select
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
 
dbc = psycopg2.connect(database='depesz', host='127.0.0.1', port=5920)
dbc.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = dbc.cursor()
cur.execute('LISTEN new_user')
 
while 1:
    if not select.select([dbc], [], [], 5) == ([], [], []):
        dbc.poll()
        while dbc.notifies:
            notify = dbc.notifies.pop()
            print "new_user %s, backed: %d" % (notify.payload, notify.pid)
```

and getting this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_email.py", line 5, in  <module>
>     import psycopg2   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line
> 50, in <module>
>     from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: **version `GLIBC_2.14' not found**
> (required by
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
```

I checked using this command:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6
```

and getting this:

> `GNU C Library stable release version 2.11.1 (20100118), ...`

So I assume 2.14 is not installed, therefore I need to install it, but how to?
I'm not quite familiar with OpenSuse, I was trying zypper but it doesn't find the package:

```
zypper in libc6
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libc6' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Thanks,

Comment: How was psycopg2 installed?  Usually it has to be compiled on the machine, unless the pre-compiled psycopg2_binary package is installed instead.

Comment: That's the thing, I have no clue, this server was set up a couple of years ago and there was no documentation left

Comment: The package name on OpenSuse appears to be simply `glibc`. But you can't necessarily update just the C runtime library without updating a lot of other components, too. A simpler approach might be to find an older version of psycopg2 which is compiled for your glibc version.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a virtualenv, and install psycopg2 into it.  If your script works in the virtualenv you could consider `sudo pip install psycopg2` to overwrite the system package.  This isn't usually recommended, but OpenSuse 11 has been out of support for some time, and it seems unlikely that any other process can be deoending on the system psycopg2 as it's unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I assume 2.14 is not installed

Correct.

> therefore I need to install it,

No: it doesn't follow that you need to install GLIBC-2.14.

What you *should* do instead is either obtain or *build from source* the `psycopg2` package *targeting* your system and your version of GLIBC.

> I have no clue, this server was set up a couple of years ago and there was no documentation left

Whoever did this setup had no clue either. Rather than making hacks which may work some of the time, or may break something else, you should do sane thing: either upgrade the entire server to some recent distribution, or install software appropriate for your old one.